# WPF Using ElementName for visibility issue

Tags: c#, wpf, datacontext

I have an issue with setting the visibility of a control when specifying the context using ElementName.
For some reason wpf seems to behave differently when using ElementName, versus using the context that is set from the code-behind.

The following code works fine. The collection contains two elements, and the button is set to visible.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfObservableCollectionVisibility.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfObservableCollectionVisibility"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" x:Name="MyWindow">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <local:EmptyListVisibilityConverter x:Key="EmptyListVisibilityConverter"></local:EmptyListVisibilityConverter>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Button Height="50" Width="100" Content="Button" VerticalAlignment="top" Visibility="{Binding MenuItems, Converter={StaticResource EmptyListVisibilityConverter}}"></Button>
        <Grid Width="200" Height="200">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}" Focusable="False">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty MenuItemsProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
                "MenuItems", typeof(ObservableCollection<MyItem>),
                typeof(MainWindow),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default (ObservableCollection<MyItem>),FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault)
            );

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MenuItems = new ObservableCollection<MyItem>();
            MenuItems.Add(new MyItem("Entry 1"));
            MenuItems.Add(new MyItem("Entry 2"));
            DataContext = this;
        }

        public ObservableCollection<MyItem> MenuItems
        {
            get => (ObservableCollection<MyItem>) GetValue(MenuItemsProperty);
            set => SetValue(MenuItemsProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public class MyItem
    {
        public MyItem(string name)
        {
            this.Name = name;
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class EmptyListVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine($"Do conversion");
            if (value == null)
            {
                Trace.WriteLine($"Conversion value was null");
                return Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
            else
            {
                ICollection list = value as ICollection;
                if (list != null)
                {
                    if (list.Count == 0)
                    {
                        Trace.WriteLine($"Count is zero");
                        return Visibility.Hidden;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Trace.WriteLine($"Count is greater than zero");
                        return Visibility.Visible;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Trace.WriteLine($"Was not a collection");
                    return Visibility.Visible;
                }
            }
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)

        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

However, when I set the ElementName context for the ItemsControl and Button, the ItemsControl still displays fine, but the Button is not shown, because the converter for some reason receives an empty collection.

```
<Button Height="50" Width="100" Content="Button" VerticalAlignment="top" Visibility="{Binding MenuItems, ElementName=MyWindow, Converter={StaticResource EmptyListVisibilityConverter}}"></Button>

...

<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems, ElementName=MyWindow}" Focusable="False">
```

I tried debugging it, but I don't understand what is wrong. I don't know where this empty collection comes from. I also don't understand why the ItemsControl works fine. I feel like either both should work, or neither.

Comment: your code works fine

Comment: @Bizhan even the one with ElementName? You see the button appear?

Comment: Yes, and the list has 2 items, look for typo

Comment: I couldn't find the issue, I asked some other people and they have the same issue, so I'm kinda stuck

Comment: Changing the button to MenuItems.Count, and changing the converter accordingly works, so it looks like when passing in the observablecollection on its own, wpf ignores the collection changed event. Which would also explain the empty collection I see when debugging.

Comment: I have posted it to [visualstudio](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/978333/wpf-using-elementname-for-visibility-issue.html) as well, but not sure if they'll respond